# Amazon AWS EC2 unexpectedly deleted root using sudo rm -rf */. How can i restore it?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have unexpectedly executed `sudo rm -rf */` on my amazon EC2 linux instance.

As soon as i saw the files deleting so i have terminated the command using `ctrl+c`.

My website instance is working fine. But i am unable to connect to the instance through ssh. Its giving `connection has closed`. On another pc there is an already existing connection, so when i do `ls` or `sudo` commands Its giving `usr/bin/ls` not found command. cd is working fine to switch the directories.

How can i be able to connect through the ssh and restore the deleted directories? OR How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You can unmount ebs of that instance, and spin up new server, mount that ebs to new server, recover your sensitive data, and setup your new instance. You can not get back what you have deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im sorry to tell you, but i don't think there is much you can do now. Setting it up completely new would be the easiest and i think most possible way to get it up working fine again. And there's this one rule, never use "sudo rm -rf" without checking your Location twice and a third time. You can delete your whole system if you do this command in your Root. So good luck.

Nico

Answer (score -1):

Let us say you deleted the `/` in the instance `I1` which has a volume attached `V1`. Now create another instance with same configuration and say it `I2` with volume `V2`.

1. So now stop `I1` detach `V1` from it and attach it to `I2`.
2. Mount the `V1` on `I2`.
3. Since both instances are from same `Ami`. They have same `uuid` so to mount by `mount -o nouuid /V1 /V2/mountpoint`.
4. Copy files in the directory `/` in `V2` to `/` in `V1`.
5. Detach it from `I2` and re-attach it `I1`.

I hope it works.